# Working through an example of Amdahl's Law with respect to percentage speedup

Tags: performance, math, computer-science, cpu-architecture, parallelism-amdahl

I am reading through "Computer Architechture: A Quantitative Approach 5th ed" and am trying to grasp Amdahl's law, when it comes to speeding up portions of the system i.e. speed up a certain percentage of the system by a certain percentage . It is easy to understand when you are talking about speeding up a system by a certain factor e.g. a system that is 10 times faster.

To give a concrete example:

You have a system, where a certain sub-system accounts for 70% of the execution time and you wish to develop a speedup which will improve the latency of this sub-system by 50%.

From the book, Amdahl's Law is listed as:

SpeedupOverall = 1/((1-FractionEnhanced)+(FractionEnhanced/SpeedupEnhanced))

I gather from the explanation of the Fractional Enhancement ("The fraction of the computation time in the original computer that can be converted to take advantage of the enhancement"), that: FractionEnhanced = 70% or 0.7.

My question here is how to reflect the speedup. The book lists it as "The improvement gained by the enhanced execution mode, that is, how much faster the task would run if the enhanced mode were used for the entire program". The book says that this would be the time that the original mode over the improvement time; in this case 70/50, or 1.4. However, where my confusion comes in is with this  [website](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~prabhu/Tutorial/CACHE/amdahl.html), where by examining the java applet code, it seems that speedup enhanced would be 1 + the percentage speedup, or 1.5. Maybe I am overthinking this as well, but I am also thinking how it could also be .7/(0.7 - 0.7*0.5), or 2 (since, 70%*50% is the actual latency reduction, in terms of the actual sub-sbstem, right?).

Working the math out, we get the following answers:

1. For SpeedupEnhanced = 70/50 = 1.4: SpeedupOverall = 1/((1-0.7)+ .7/1.4) = 1.25
2. For SpeedupEnhanced = 1+0.5 = 1.5: SpeedupOverall = 1/((1-0.7)+ .7/1.5) = 1.3043
3. For SpeedupEnhanced = 0.7/(0.7-0.7*0.5) = 2: SpeedupOverall = 1/((1-0.7)+.7/2) = 1.54

Which one would be the correct speedup here? The second seems to make sense to me, but the book seems to imply that the first is correct. Any help by way of references or explanations as to how to grasp this type of speedup would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third answer (1.54x total speedup) is a correct one,  because "speedup enhanced" is a  non-dimensional value characterizing  only enhanced part execution time change (in "x" units). Note that speedup enhanced  is simply equal to 70/(70*0.5) in your case.

Overall there are lots of possible confusions wrt amdahl law and gustafson law interpretation. Surprisingly, good starting reading is wikipedia page about amdahl law. It will particularly remap you to more traditional interpretation which makes an emphasize on parallel computations and number of processors instead of "enhanced speedup" notion. Deeper and exhaustive reading could be found  on reference page of professor Gustafson, who "invented" alternate "optimistical law". After studying all the materials, you will find that the notion of "speedup" is even more interesting and unambigous.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Was my line of thinking for the third option correct though, or was I just a little too convenient by choosing 50%?

Say, I chose 55%, would SpeedupEnhanced be equal to 0.7/(0.7-0.7*0.55)?

Comment: In case 55% (Y%) charaterizes sub-system' improvement (e.g. subsystem' execution time decreased by 55%) then SpeedupEnhanced = 0.7/(0.7*0.55)= 1/0.55. So SpeedupEnhanced is simply equal to 1/Y%, where (100-Y%) characterizes sub-system (execution time) after impovement. 1/Y seems to be too simple formula, which may confuse you. The origin of confusion is that the law' interpretation in your book tries to generalize things, which by its origin (parallel execution time) are a bit more intuitive and natural. But well, overgeneralization isn't bad because of more issues with Gustafson vs Amdahl

Comment: Ok, I think I get you now. Do you have any references I could have to read further about this?

Comment: I am just confused as to why, in the case where you are speeding up a subsystem accounting for X% by Y%, SpeedupEnhanced would be 1/Y% and not 1/(1-Y)%. Using the 70,55% example, it makes sense to me because this would be equivalent to 70%/31.5%  (1/(1-Y%)) which would be the speedup, and not 70%/38.5% (1/Y%) or is my thinking all fuddled here? 1/Y% seems like it would work in the case where you are speeding up the entire system and not just an X% subsystem...

Comment: Well, it depends on how you define Y.  I defined/interpreted it so that Y is a Delta(i.e. BY how much you improved original time). You coulld define it in opposite way (Y is  a ratio of improved time as compared to original time) and it will end up in your formula; but in last case I dont understand why did you use conjunction  «BY» (i'm not a native speaker:))

Comment: Ahh ok, I didn't read carefully. I follow your logic and it was what I had stated previously (in more words and confusing language... sorry about that).

Thanks again for your help.